# Is there a way to put the pseudo-element outside the targeted element?

Tags: html, css

What I know is that :before and :after pseudo-element is inserted before and after the children of the targeted element. Is there a way to move it outside the targeted element? And it will become it's sibling not a child of it. Literally not visually.

Comment: Visually? or literally?

Comment: That's a great question. Literally.

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible to manipulate `pseudo-elements` (even) with JavaScript, because they don't exist in the DOM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?